# Disable disc cache

Tags: javascript, spring-security

I'm working on project which require deletion of browser history.I came to know that browser will not save history urls if disc cache is disabled.Is it possible to disable disc cache in application?If it is possible then how to disable disc cache in web based application?

Comment: That's not possible. Though, you could use `location.replace` for all your links instead to overwrite the history everytime someone clicks a link.

Comment: i already tried that.but it is not deleting the urls from browser history

Comment: it's not possible. imagine if browser vendors allowed access to that sort of functionality. what is the problem you have that deleting history will solve?

Comment: it is for some security related purpose